# Why is my pg-query result throwing a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-query

I am creating a node function to create a user in a `PostgreSQL` database.  I'm using `node.js`, `pg` and `pg-query` to communicate from the app to the database.

Before I insert a new record Im trying to validate the email address does not already exist.

I am not sure why my `result.rows[0].id` is throwing a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error`  Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ) I am using the correct syntax to access the results of my query.

This is the function:

```
/* POST create user */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    var newHash = hash(req.body.password, salt);

    query.connectionParameters = connString;
    query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = $1',[req.body.email], function(err, result) {
    if (err){
        console.log('Insert error: ' + err);
    }

    // If email exists, return error else insert new record
    if(result.rows[0].id != null) {
        query('INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [req.body.email, newHash, salt], function(err, result) {
              if (err){
                console.log('Insert error: ' + err);
              }
              res.send( ( err === null ) ? { msg: '' } : { msg:err }  );
            });
    }
    else{
        console.log(result);
        res.send({msg:'User already exists'});
    }
    });
});
```

And the error I am receiving is as follows:

```
/home/robot/workspace/userapp/routes/users.js:35
    if(result.rows[0].id != null) {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at /home/robot/workspace/userapp/routes/users.js:35:23
    at Function.onSuccess (/home/robot/workspace/userapp/node_modules/pg-query/index.js:55:7)
    at null.callback (/home/robot/workspace/userapp/node_modules/pg-query/node_modules/okay/index.js:7:16)
    at Query.handleReadyForQuery (/home/robot/workspace/userapp/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:80:10)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/robot/workspace/userapp/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:158:19)
    at emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/robot/workspace/userapp/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
```

I'm new to `javascript` and `node` so it may be something very obvious.  Here is the [`pg-query` documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query) if it helps.

** SOLUTION **

Changing the conditional to `if(result[0].num == 0) {` solved the problem.  `pg-query` does not return a property called `rows` apparently.

Answer (score 1):

** SOLUTION **

Changing the conditional to `if(result[0].num == 0) {` solved the problem. `pg-query` does not return a property called rows apparently.

Comment: Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), if you want to save time in processing the return result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the `rows` object is `undefined` to indicate that there are no users with the given email address.  You could change the query to `select count(*) as num from users where email = $1`.  This would ensure a result, and you can test if `result.rows[0].num == 0`.

Comment: Even with that change I get the same error response.  If the query executes successfully I would image the `result` would have something in it.  No rows returned or a value or something....

Comment: 2 things:  first see my edits (notice I added a column alias), 2nd if that isn't the problem I would start adding logging to examine the contents or the `err` and `result` objects.

Comment: Changing the conditional to this did the trick:  `if(result[0].num == 0) {`  I guess pg-query doesnt return a property of rows like pg does.